# Roughly how much data is used when playing Mass Effect 3 muliplayer online?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Roughly how much data does Mass Effect 3 multiplayer use, assuming that I use voice chat? Is it even possible to get a reasonable estimate for this?

Comment: I apologise for the ambiguity. What I mean is how much data the game uses up per hour. I have a small data cap on my mobile and I want to see if tethering is worthwhile

Answer (score 2):

That is hard to tell as it's dependent on

- Playstyle
- Number of players
- Number of mods or extensions running on the server
- Location of the Server

Generally, You could test it by

- Resetting the data counter (via the system or a third-party app)
- Play for a specified amount of time
- Check the data used

This number should give you a rough idea, if it is worth to you spending your data on it or not.